# Div gets misplaced on text insertion and text goes out of div

Tags: css, layout

Here is the jsfiddle of the problem, http://jsfiddle.net/B77G2/2/

The problem is, that when I put text in a div, the div moves down(the div with the home id in the jsfiddle  has the text in  it, you can remove t## e text to see it working properly). If there is no text in a div, it appears fine and in line with the other divs like its supposed to.

And the text goes out of the div even though I'm using word-wrap.

Why is this happenning and how can I fix it?

Everything has been minified for showing in the jsfiddle, I hope my problem is clear.

Here's the html

```
<div id="container">
        <div class="fade" id="fade1" onclick="slide('prev')"><</div>
        <div class="fade" id="fade2" onclick="slide('next')">></div>

        <div id="sliding-container">
            <div class="slide leftmost" id="followme">
            </div>

            <div class="slide left" id="projects">

            </div>

            <div class="slide current" id="home">
                <p>Y u do dis :( fjsdahkfjdhsjfhdkjfsdjhfjsk djskfhdjfurt</p> // <---- the div thats being shown in the middle
            </div>

            <div class="slide right" id="knowledge">

            </div>

            <div class="slide rightmost" id="contact">

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Provide the js code as it is empty in the jsfiddle under Javascript.

Comment: @JavierBrooklyn the js doesnt matter here, it's not having any effect :/ no need to downgrade the question, the behaviour is still going wrong in the jsfiddle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like a `vertical-align` issue. Try setting it explicitly:

```
.slide { vertical-align:top; }
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/B77G2/3/)

Browsers have a slightly complex algorithm for computing the `baseline` (default value) of `vertical-align` for floated elements or with `inline-block` display. Giving it a explicitly `top` value usually fixes the issue.

---

Oh I almost forgot to add why the line isn't breaking. It is simple: Your `white-space:nowrap` is inherited to descendants elements and it forces text to be in a single line. All you have to do is reset it before reaching the text content which require `word-wrap`, so:

```
.slide { white-space: normal; word-wrap: break-word; }
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/B77G2/7/)

---

For the `vertical-align` explanation, it is a little complex, here is the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-linebox/#vertical-align) for the default `vertical-align` value - `baseline`:

> Align the ‘alphabetic’ baseline of the element with the ‘alphabetic’ baseline of the parent element. If the inline element doesn't have an ‘alphabetic’ baseline, align the bottom of the box, including its margin for replaced elements, with the parent's ‘alphabetic’ baseline. The dominant baseline is set to ‘alphabetic’ if there is no parent or if there is a flow orientation change between this element and its parent, otherwise it is set to ‘no-change’.

Better explain with an example. Open this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B77G2/4/). I've added some text in-between the slides which represent the parent's alphabetic `baseline`. The `baseline` is the red line in this image:

[image]

As you can see, when the child has an alphabetic baseline, both parent and child alphabetic baselines are aligned as per the first line of the spec: "Align the ‘alphabetic’ baseline of the element with the ‘alphabetic’ baseline of the parent element."

The other sibling slides do not have any non empty/white-space-only TextNodes, therefore they do not have an alphabetic baseline to align with and the second statement of the spec kicks in: "If the inline element doesn't have an ‘alphabetic’ baseline, align the bottom of the box, including its margin with the parent's ‘alphabetic’ baseline."

Comment: thanks! it works! could you tell me why the text goes out of the div when I still use word-wrap: break-word as well, your answer would be complete then :)

Comment: I understand how this all works now, and thank you alot for the explanation, but what I meant to ask is that the text is flowing out of the div,  I want to keep it in, I tried adding word-wrap: break-word; but it's not working, so what can I do here to fix that? That was also in the question, and I admit,I might not have said that clearly in the question, but could you tell me what to do to fix that?

Comment: @JahanzebKhan `white-space:nowrap` forces the text to be in a single line and is inherited by the descendants, so you just have to reset it on the slides: `.slide { white-space: normal; }` [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/B77G2/6/)

Comment: And my bad, I'm a little too sleepy, didn't read your first comment properly. `:P` Updated answer.