# CSS display:table breaks when first element in table-cell is not text

Tags: html, css

I'm using display:table to create a layout of nested sets of rows and columns.  I've noticed that the alignment of columns seems to break when the first element in a table-cell is something other than text.  Admittedly, I haven't tested which elements cause this, but there's an example in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ekx4v/

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
  #container {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    display:table;
  }
  #column1 {
    display:table-cell;
    background-color:blue;
  }
  #column2 {
    display:table-cell;
    background-color:red;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
  <div id="column1">
    Col1
    <form>
      <select size="2">
        <option>Options go here...</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="column2">Col2</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Removing the "Col1" text causes the second column to go out of alignment.  In case this doesn't reproduce on other browsers, here are some screenshots, taken in Chrome:

With "Col1":

[image: correct alignment]

Without "Col1":

[image: incorrect alignment]

I get the same results in Firefox.  Is this expected behavior?  If so, is there a workaround so that I don't have to put text at the beginning of every div?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is all due to the [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/vertical-align) that defaults to `baseline`, it is the expected behavior as your examples have very differently alphabetic baselines. Actually, without text content the `div` doesn't have an alphabetic baseline, so bottom of the box is aligned with the parent's alphabetic baseline as per the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-linebox/#vertical-align).

Thankfully it is easy to workaround:

```
#container > div {
   vertical-align:top;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/usogam/3/edit)

---

Here's a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14918664/1331430) (check last section), though your use case is a bit different:

Simply put, when there's no text content, your `select` element will be aligned with the parent's alphabetic baseline. This will push the parent's alphabetic baseline down so the `select` can still fit inside the parent having its bottom aligned with the parent's alphabetic baseline. All other `div`s' baselines are still aligned to this baseline, which has been pushed down by the `select`.

By adding text content before your `form` element, your `div` will have an alphabetic baseline which doesn't push the parent's baseline as the `select` would. All `div`s' baselines are still aligned to the parent's alphabetic baseline as in the previous case, but this time the parent's baseline hasn't been pushed down.

Here's a rough demonstration of the 2 paragraphs above (beware of mad MS-Paint skills):

[image]

As you can see, in the second scenario, the baseline of the parent is pushed down so the `select` element can still fit inside the parent while having its bottom aligned with the parent's baseline.

`vertical-align:top` saves the browser from having to comply with such complex rules. It may also save us from many headaches when applying it to floated/inline-block/table'd content.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer!  This was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
display:block;
float:left;
height: 200px;
```

On those two cells.  In my experience the allowing the divs to vertically align somewhere other than the top is the reason to use `table-cell`.  If you don't need that there may be a better way to do what you want.  Displaying these as block gives you more control over how text is displayed inside.